# How to limit Spring Cloud Gateway by IP

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I need to restrict access to my Spring Cloud Gateway to a specific set of client IPs (basically to have a IP whitelist). I am sure there is a simple way to do it just but tuning the yaml configuration for the gateway and not needing any custom filter coding for that simple task. How can I do it?

spring.cloud.gateway.security... ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the RemoteAddr Route Predicate Factory.You can find more details on how to set it up and configure it [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-remoteaddr-route-predicate-factory).

Comment: Same link pointing at the latest documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-remoteaddr-route-predicate-factory

Answer (score 1):

adding to the answer of @OlgaMaciaszek. Here is how you can use RemoteAddr Predicate. . (if you want to programatically add the whitelisted Ips instead of hardcoding in yaml file)

```js
List<String> whitelist = <your list of whitelisted Ips> ;

RemoteAddrRoutePredicateFactory predicateFactory = new RemoteAddrRoutePredicateFactory();

if (!predicateFactory.apply(predicateFactory.newConfig()
                .setRemoteAddressResolver(XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver.maxTrustedIndex(2)).setSources(whitelist))
                .test(exchange)) {
       log.error("IP not whitelisted. Stopping futher communications.");
       return GatewayResponseHelper.setIPNotWhiteListResponse(exchange);
            }
log.info("IP is whitelisted. Proceeding with request.");
return chain.filter(exchange);
```

you can use XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver if your service is behind some proxy layer. or default RemoteAddressResolver. Go through the class/doc for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GlobalFilter to restrict access. It filters all requests and you can put your customized logic in the filter if it is not a simple remote address restrict.

```
@Bean
@Order(-1)
public GlobalFilter whitelistFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        // TODO - init your whitelist
        List<String> whitelist = new ArrayList<>();
        whitelist.add("localhost");
        // verify request remote address
        String id = exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getHostName();
        if (!whitelist.contains(id)) {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            return response.setComplete();
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}
```